# 4-bit Shift register with flip flop

Tags: vhdl, flip-flop, shift-register

I want to build a 4-bit shift register using D FlipFlop , but I don't understand this diagram.
[image]

This code is given to me for shift register

```
ENTITY shift4 IS
 PORT ( D : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) ; 
 Enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
 Sin : IN STD_LOGIC;
 Clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
 Q : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) ) ; 
END shift4 ;
```

And I wrote this code for flip flop

```
entity flipflop is
 port ( D_in : in std_logic;
 CLK : in std_logic;
 CLR : in std_logic;
 Q_out : out std_logic
 );
end flipflop; 


architecture behavior of flipflop is
begin
process(CLK)
begin
if CLR='0' then null;
elsif RISING_EDGE(CLK) then
Q_out <= D_in;
end if;
end process ;
end behavior ;
```

What I don't get from this diagram is how am I supposed to use D and how to port map flipflop with this inputs and outputs. I tried this

```
FF1: flipflop port map(Sin,Clock,Enable, Q(3));
FF2: flipflop port map(Sin,Clock,Enable, Q(2));
FF3: flipflop port map(Sin,Clock,Enable, Q(1));
FF4: flipflop port map(Sin,Clock,Enable, Q(0));
```

But obviously it's not the case because I have to use the D also, but I can't find a way for using all the variables.

Comment: To understand the circuit diagram consider that in a D Flip Flop the state of Input "D" is passed to the output Q on the rising edge of CLK. When D subsequently changes, this has no effect on Q until the next rising edge of CLK ... so if you place a "1" to Sin, on the 1st rising edge of CLK it reaches Q3 (which is also the input to the next D Flip Flop ... at the 2nd rising edge it reaches Q2 ... etc etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FF1: flipflop port map(Sin,Clock,Enable, Q(3));
```

This is good, it does exactly what your diagram ask.

```
FF2: flipflop port map(Sin,Clock,Enable, Q(2));
```

This is not good. This connects the input `D` of `FF2` to `Sin`, while the diagram connects it to `Q(3)`. You could try doing something like:

```
FF2: flipflop port map(Q(3),Clock,Enable, Q(2));
```

But unless your tool is compatible uses VHDL-2008, it will fail (safer to assume it doesn't). This is because in VHDL you can't read an output of your entity. Instead, you have to define an internal signal, use it for all assignments, and assign `Q` to it.

```
architecture structural of shift4 is
    signal Q_i : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- _i stands for internal
begin
    Q <= Q_i; -- Drive output port from the internal version

    FF1: flipflop(Sin, Clock, Enable, Q_i(3));
```

Comment: I get it, but what about the D in the shift4 entity? We are not using it at all

Comment: Mmm, didn't see it. From the diagram, it's useless and shouldn't be there. There is not `D` input on your top diagrams, only `Sin`, `Clock`, `Enable` and `Q`.